# Pass String in C++ COM dll from C# function

Tags: c#, c++, .net-4.5, intptr

Function Interface of dll;

I think in dll function looks like, with datatype BSTR

```
CustomConvert(BSTR dataStr)

{........}
```

dll Interface:

```
CustomConvert(IntPtr dataStr)    //Returns strings
```

The data I need to pass is something like this:

```
string strTemp = "pŒ®í§…Êtf°B²bßZÃQô"; // something like this
obj.CustomConvert(strTemp);
```

But I am getting the exception "string" cannot convert to "System.IntPtr";
After searching in internet I found something like this.

```
obj.CustomConvert(System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.StringToBSTR(strTemp));
```

But System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.StringToBSTR(strTemp) convert strTemp in numerical numbers like 2035295. But I need to pass the actual value in strTemp.

Any help or suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To pass a `BSTR` you can do something like:

```
public static extern void CustomConvert([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.BStr)] string dataStr);
```

and then pass the `string` directly without doing anything.

Note that in the `CustomConvert` you mustn't free the `BSTR`, because it is "owned" by the C#.

Comment: @NearlyCrazy Ah... Then the `obj.CustomConvert(System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.StringToBSTR(strTemp));` is correct. Remember that you'll have to free it with `Marshal.FreeBSTR`, so it is better if you use a variable, like `IntPtr temp = Marshal.StringToBSTR(strTemp); obj.CustomConvert(temp); Marshal.FreeBSTR(temp);`

Comment: just curious : what happens if I don't use FreeBSTR ??

Comment: @NearlyCrazy Someone has to free the memory allocated for the `BSTR`.  Sadly it isn't always clear **who** has to do it. Normally if you call a method passing a `BSTR`, the caller (you) maintains the ownership of the `BSTR`, so has to free it. Clearly if you call a method that returns a BSTR, the caller (you) is given the ownership of the `BSTR` and has to free it.

Comment: @ xanatos: I have just implement your suggestion. But while I run 'Marshal.FreeBSTR(temp);'. My 'Visual Studio' get stopped but no exception caugth on try catch.

Comment: @xanatos *Sadly it isn't always clear who has to do it* and *Normally* are the keywords here :-) Clearly it is already freed by the called method. Remove the `Marshal.FreeBSTR(temp)` and annotate somewhere that the method seems to free the passed `BSTR`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/81600/discussion-between-nearlycrazy-and-xanatos).